# Laravel 5 validate cloned fields using form request

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I have a form using [cloneya jQuery plugin](https://github.com/yapapaya/jquery-cloneya) to clone form elements. The elements that will be cloned looks like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Item name</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="name[]" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="count">Item count</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="count[]" type="text">
</div>
```

As you can see, each input will be an array instead of string. I want to validate those using [Laravel Form Request](http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation). Here's my rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'  => 'required|between:3,50',
        'count' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ];
}
```

But that's not working. When I submitted the form, I got the following error message:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I've been searching for solution, but can't find the appropriate one. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Basically, in your `rules()` method, you need to determine how many `name` and `count` elements there are in the `POST` and then create rules for each of them:

```php
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];

    foreach ($this->request->get('name') as $index => $val) {
        $rules['name.' . $index] = 'required|between:3,50';
    }

    foreach ($this->request->get('count') as $index => $val) {
        $rules['count.' . $index] = 'required|integer|min:1';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Please check [this post](http://ericlbarnes.com/laravel-array-validation/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Vol%201%20Issue%2047&utm_content=Vol%201%20Issue%2047%20CID_779d6bca415960e99ab73e5a2a08286c&utm_source=email%20marketing&utm_term=Read%20the%20Tutorial).

Comment: Yeah, I've been tried that way, but it's still not working. I think the cause is about using the key/index in field name, like `<input name="count[0]" type="text">`. But my issue is that we don't know how many name and count user will submit.

Comment: You don't really have to know how many `name` and `count` there are since you're using a `foreach` loop. `<input name="count[0]">` should correspond to `$rules['count.0']` in the rules array. Have you tried to intentionally cause validation errors and dump the `$errors` variable in your view? Could you post the dumped `$errors`?

Comment: You're right, we're using `foreach` here, so that we don't have to worry about how many fields submitted. But it's still showing the same error as before: `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`. I can't dump the `$errors` variable since the request haven't been validated yet by the rules.

Comment: Then it's not a validator issue. Could you post your controller's code? Particularly the method that receives the POST request.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the controller's side. Laravel shows the error when trying to process the request with the given rules. So the problem should be in the request class.